# Svelte conditonal attribute render

Tags: typescript, svelte

On a bit thin ice here, but I'm trying to conditionally render the on: directive as this.

```
<li
  class="badge"
  animate:flip={{ delay: 0, duration: 250, easing: quintOut }}
  {...isBadgesClickable && {
    ['on:click']: onBadgeClick()
  }}
></li>
```

What i want to do is to possible render multiple attributes and/or directives conditionally. I know the example above won't work, but how am I supposed to go about it to acheved said logic ?

Comment: Why don't just wrap the li tag in an if block, then you can have the li with the on directive in the if block, and the li tag without on directive in the else block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svelte doesn't let you spread directives like that. Assuming `onBadgeClick` is the function you want to run on click, you can do something like this:

```svelte
<li
  class="badge"
  animate:flip={{ delay: 0, duration: 250, easing: quintOut }}
  on:click={isBadgesClickable && onBadgeClick}
></li>
```

Though note that a click event handler will still be added to the element when `isBadgesClickable` is false. It will just only run when `isBadgesClickable` is true.

Also, adding a click event to a `<li>` is generally discouraged because of accessibility and a `<button>` is usually more appropriate. Make sure you can interact with the element with the keyboard and that it's properly identified to screen readers.

Comment: Great, yeah that's what i thought, but glad you are confirming my theories ;)
I ended up with doing it just as you did in your answer, so I'll mark it as solved. And if anyone else come looking here, this is currently not possible with svelte.